# can't get data from php by calling post in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working with prepared statements in php when getting data from my database, as I was told that that is a secured way to work. The problem is that I am not able to retrieve the data returned by a query from an external php file in javascript.
I do can see the data when I send the parameter directly in the url by changing post, to get method: (localhost/prueba_prepared_statements.php?transportista=1)
But when I use an ajax call in javascript I can't see anything.

this is my php file code:
prueba_prepared_statement.php:

```
<?php
    include "conexion.php";
    $input_variable = $_POST['input_variable'];
    $sql = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT COD, NAME FROM TABLE WHERE COD = :input_variable");
    oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':input_variable', $input_variable);
    $resultado = oci_execute($sql);

    if ($resultado){
        $sql= oci_fetch_array($sql);
        echo json_encode($sql);
    }
?>
```

this is my javascript file where I am sending the parameter and want to retrieve the data from my php file:

```
function trae_transportista(){
    input_variable = $('#input_variable').val();
    $.ajax({
        url : "prueba_prepared_statement.php", 
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data: {"input_variable" : input_variable},
        success : function(data){
            alert(data.NAME);  
        }           
    });
};
```

The above code in javascript is ok if I don't use prepared statement for my query, as this:

```
 <?php
    include "conexion.php";
    $input_variable = $_POST['input_variable'];
    $sql= oci_parse($conn,"SELECT COD, NAME FROM TABLE WHERE COD=" . $input_variable);
    $resultado = oci_execute($sql);
    if ($resultado){
        $sql= oci_fetch_array($sql);
        echo json_encode($sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are appending user input to a DB Query... Here's [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) information. Here is a link to [oci_bind_by_name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) which will allow you to properly bind params to prepared statements as you should be doing. I don't think any of this will resolve your problem (hence the comment) but I can't stand SQL Injection - it's too easy to fix.

Comment: What data type are you _actually_ getting back in your success function? Try `console.log(typeof data); console.log(data);` and see what you have to work with.

Comment: the result of the query is a unique row composed by a number(cod) and a varchar(name), but when I run console.log(typeof data) it says the data is: Object.

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` and see what _structure_ that object has …

Comment: for some reason my code is working..guess windows had something to do with it since the only thing I did was rewrite my php file :S